# VLOOKUP issues not finding a value that's in its range

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

Here's a [link to a copy of my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aD7r8_LzxUyQYFIe-o5EiopNKBd2KNaT_h-oeQCeiQs/edit?usp=sharing).

I am attempting to do the same formula using a VLOOKUP in four sheets to do a calculation called LSI.

In the first sheet I have the raw data from a form coming in.

In the second sheet I have used a query to just get the Dive tank data. The sheet labeled `DiveTank` has the formula to calculate LSI and it works perfectly in cell `M3`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A),IF(row(A3:A)=3,"LSI", E3:E + VLOOKUP(F3:F, 'LSI-Index'!A4:B40,2,1) + VLOOKUP(G3:G, Alkalinity,2,1) + VLOOKUP(H3:H,Calcium,2,1) - 12.1),))
```

All the other sheets have the exact same set up and use a query to grab just that pool's data exactly like I did for `DiveTank`.  If you look at the sheet `DSM` in cell `M3` it has the same formula that `DiveTank` uses yet it doesn't work at all.

It seems to get stuck trying to `VLOOKUP` the `Named Range` in the sheet `LSI-Index`called `Alkalinity`.  I also tested the other VLOOKUPs and the only named range that seems to work is the `Temperature`.  I even tried just using the actual range like so:

```
VLOOKUP(H3:H, 'LSI-Index'!C4:D38,2,1)
```

I still get this error even if `100` is in the range:

> ERROR: Did not find value "100" in VLOOKUP evaluation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try formatting `Water Tests` as Number, Number.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Any Idea why it worked without having to have similar number formats for the `DiveTank`

Comment: Pointed me in correct direction but with changing both columns to Plain Text, thanks.